# Display Message with Qualtrics Hot Spot Question Type

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics

I'm trying to get Qualtrics' Hot Spot question type to display a message to users when a region is clicked.

I thought I could do this adding an alert function (below) but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){
        $('NextButton').click();
    alert("Your bid has been accepted.");
    };

    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        this.hideNextButton();
});
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!